# Missing value when export listview to xls file in c#

Tags: c#, excel, listview, export

The problem is i can export listview to excel file successfully, but when i try to open it. They said it can read only. And some value in file is change to '0'

Example:

> 10379743021704072015 -> 10379743021704000000
>
> 10379743021704072015 -> 1.0379743021704E+019

**Note:** I use Microsoft excel 2016 to open it.

```
using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel 
Workbook|*.xlsx", ValidateNames = true })
                {
                    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    Workbook wb = 
app.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
                    Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)app.ActiveSheet;
                    app.Visible = false;

                    ws.Cells[1, 1] = "date";
                    ws.Cells[1, 2] = "time";
                    ws.Cells[1, 3] = "harness";
                    ws.Cells[1, 4] = "ModuleHtr";
                    ws.Cells[1, 5] = "MainIp";
                    ws.Cells[1, 6] = "Antenna";
                    ws.Cells[1, 7] = "AirBag";
                    ws.Cells[1, 8] = "Screw Torque 1";
                    ws.Cells[1, 9] = "Screw Torque 2";
                    ws.Cells[1, 10] = "Screw Torque 3";
                    ws.Cells[1, 11] = "Scan Switch";
                    ws.Cells[1, 12] = "Cluster";
                    ws.Cells[1, 13] = "E-Test AirBag";
                    ws.Cells[1, 14] = "E-Test Cluster";
                    ws.Cells[1, 15] = "E-Test Column";
                    ws.Cells[1, 16] = "E-Test Sensor";
                    ws.Cells[1, 17] = "E-Test Result";
                    ws.Cells[1, 18] = "QC (Ok or Nok)";
                    ws.Cells[1, 19] = "Serial Number";
                    int i = 2;
                    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
                    {
                        ws.Cells[i, 1] = item.SubItems[0].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 2] = item.SubItems[1].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 3] = item.SubItems[2].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 4] = item.SubItems[3].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 5] = item.SubItems[4].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 6] = item.SubItems[5].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 7] = item.SubItems[6].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 8] = item.SubItems[7].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 9] = item.SubItems[8].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 10] = item.SubItems[9].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 11] = item.SubItems[10].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 12] = item.SubItems[11].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 13] = item.SubItems[12].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 14] = item.SubItems[13].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 15] = item.SubItems[14].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 16] = item.SubItems[15].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 17] = item.SubItems[16].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 18] = item.SubItems[17].Text;
                        ws.Cells[i, 19] = item.SubItems[18].Text;
                        
                        i++;
                    }
                    wb.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    MessageBox.Show("Exported");
                }
            }
```

Comment: in excel try format cell to edit value appearance

Comment: The change in the numbers is just the limits of numerical precision in Excel cell values.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you run the `Save` option, you are creating a workbook, but not closing it, so it is read only. Even when you stop debugging or close your program, it will still be read only.

You need to close the workbook each time you run your save command. So you need to add the workbook close statement to the end of your code like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Exported")
wb.Close();
```